# Verified SAB do not get returned through Google Places API Web Service or even the Google Maps Javascript API

Tags: javascript, ios, google-maps, google-places

We have tried using the Google Places API on iOS and Google Places Web Service to get a verified SAB (service area business), that is a business that has an address but that does not have a physical location, rather it serves a certain area.

Here is an example business "Japanese Mobile Hairdresser Scissor Paper Rock" that you can try.

After trying nearby, textsearch, autocomplete and other APIs we came to the conclusion that because there is no physical address and the business actually just serves an area it makes sense that the Google Places API does not return this business or any other SAB.

Using Google Maps directly though does return the business and so does the sample that Google has on this page about the js API

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder

Also searching around on the internet you will find articles like this

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/map-maker/0-0wplytssg

that seem to suggest that although SABs will not show on a map they will return in the search results of a map as the above sample suggest and also using Google Maps directly.

Logically then we tried to create a web page that uses the js API example to see if we can search for the "Japanese Mobile Hairdresser Scissor Paper Rock" business only to find out that although it gets returned by Google's sample when we add our API key and host that file on a server neither this business nor any other SAB gets returned.

Has anyone else experienced this problem? Is there any way to get SABs by using any of the available APIs from Google, whether it is Google Maps or Google Places or any other? Do you know if Google returns different results on their maps rather than the APIs?

FYI all these APIs are enabled on the Google Console API

- Google Places API for iOS
- Google Places API Web Service
- Google Maps SDK for iOS
- Google Maps JavaScript API
- Google Maps Geocoding API

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey, I know it's been a while but I'm looking for a solution to this exact problem. Was wondering if you (or anyone else) were able to figure it out or get a work around?